# I want to select wav files from one directory and save the features as png file with the same filename

Tags: python, png, filenames, wav

I want to plot MFCC features of .wav files(more than one file) from a folder and save them with the same file name.png to another folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problem are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through them like this:

```py
import os
import imageio

audio_folder = "./audio/"
image_folder = "./images/"

for filename in os.listdir(audio_folder):
    path = os.path.join(audio_folder, filename)
    # -=-=-=- read audio file using `path`

    # -=-=-=- convert to image here -=-=-=-
    image = ...
    
    new_name = filename.split(".wav")[0] + "png"
    path = os.path.join(image_folder, new_name)
    imageio.imwrite(path, image)
```

this would require the package `imageio` which can be simply installed using:

```
pip install imageio
```